# Restore AFS from /vicepa to a normal directory

Tags: restore, file-server, afs

This may be the wrong way of going about things, but I was hoping there is some hope. Our afs configuration has completely gone haywire, but the volumes within the /vicepa partition are still present. Is there any way to restore these .vol files to something readable without having to use an existing AFS system?

Comment: Did you manage to extract the data? Maybe this is a question for serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this; it's not the "wrong way" of doing things, and isn't even that uncommon.

You can use [voldump(8)](http://docs.openafs.org/Reference/8/voldump.html) to generate a "vos dump"-style volume dump directly from /vicepa contents, without going through the volserver. Once you have that, you can get the actual files back using [restorevol(1)](http://docs.openafs.org/Reference/1/restorevol.html). Or you could restore the volume to another AFS fileserver using "vos restore" (manpage "vos_restore(1)").

There is also a tool called afsdump_extract that can be used instead of restorevol. But restorevol is usually easier to find; restorevol is part of OpenAFS, and afsdump_extra is part of "dumpscan".

Comment: I can't confirm that this is the correct answer, since this was a long time ago. It is, however, at least some information for future users who need similar advice.